# Android sqlite foreign key error check not working?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I have 2 tables Users and Computers

Users = (id, name, age)

id -> primary key

Computers = (comp_id, comp_model_name, user_id)

comp_id -> primary key

user_id -> foreign key to users table user_id field.
As I want one computer to be used by a single person.

```
if (db != null) {
        if (!db.isReadOnly) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

db?.execSQL(
    "create table Users " +
            "(id integer primary key, name text, age integer)"
)


db?.execSQL(
    "create table Computers " +
            "(id integer primary key, model_name text, user_id integer," +
            " FOREIGN KEY (user_id) references Users (id))")
```

What problem I am seeing is that, if for 3rd field of computer object I specify a value which is not in Users table id field it doesn't throw an error. It is accepting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable foreign key constraint support you must override [`onConfigure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and call [`setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(boolean)):

```
override fun onConfigure(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)
}
```